# Exclude range of directories in find command

Tags: linux, shell, find

I have directory called `test` which has sub folders in the date range like `01`,`02`,...`31`. This all sub folders contain .bz2 files in it. I need to search all the files with .bz2 extension using find command but excluding particular range of directories. I know about `find . -name ".bz2" -not -path "./01/*"`, but writing `-not -path "./01/*"` would be so pathetic if I would want to skip 10 directories. So how would I skip `01..19` subdirectories in my `find` command ?

Comment: Questions like this would be better suited for [linux.se].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use wildcards in the pattern for the option `-not -path`:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.bz2" -not -path "./0*/*" -not -path "./1*/*
```

this will exclude all directories starting with 0 or 1. Or even better:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.bz2" -not -path "./[01]*/*"
```

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, you can help `find` by using `-prune` rather than `-not -path` - that will avoid even looking inside the relevant directories.

To your main point - you can build a wildcard for your example (numeric 01 to 19):

```
find . -path './0[1-9]' -prune -o -path './1[0-9]' -prune -o -print
```

If you are willing to also ignore "00" (perhaps you know it doesn't exist), then you could combine to a single wildcard:

```
find . -path './[01][0-9]' -prune -o -print
```

If your range is less convenient (e.g. 05 to 25) you might want to build the range into a bash variable, then interpolate that into the `find` command:

```
a=("-path ./"{05..25}" -prune -o")
find . ${a[*]} -print -prune
```

(you might want to `echo "${a[*]}"` or `printf '%s\n' ${a[*]}` to see how it's working)

Answer (score 4):

For me, I found the **find** command as a standalone tool somehow cumbersome. Therefore, I always end up using a combination of **find** just for the recursive file search and **grep** to make the actual exculsion/inclusion stuff. Finally I hand over the results to a third command which will perform the actions, like **rm** to remove files for example.

My generic command would look something like this:

```
find [root-path] | grep (-v)? -E "cond1|cond2|...|condN" | [action-performing-tool]
```

- root-path is where to start the search recursively
- add **-v** option is used to invert the matching results.
- cond1 - condN, the conditions for the matching. When -v is involed then this are the conditions to **not** match.
- the action-performing-tool does the actual work

For example you want to remove all files **not** matching some conditions in the current directory:

```
find . -not -name "\." | grep -v -E "cond1|cond2|cond3|...|condN" | xargs rm -rf
```

As you can see, we are searching in the current directory indicated by the dot as root-path: then we want to invert the matching results, because we want all files **not** matching our conditions: and finally we pass all files found to **rm** in order to delete them: I add -rf to recursive/force delete all files. I used the find command with *-not -name "."* to exclude the current directory indicated normally by dot.

For the actuall question: Assume we have a directory using .git and .metadata directory and we want to exclude them in our search:

```
find . -not -name "\." | grep -v -E ".git|.metadata" | [action-performing-tool]
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to exclude child directory under parent directory then this might be useful:

E.g.- You have parent directory "ParentDir" and it has two child directories "Child1, Child2". You wan to read files from "Chiled2" only and skip "Child1". Then this will help.

```
find ./ParentDir ! -path "./ParentDir/Child1*" -name *.<extention>
```